# Vertical fixed nav flex content on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a nav essentially like the one found on the google venture website (http://www.gv.com/portfolio/).

I want the nav to be a vertical and fixed on the left of the page and pop out on hover. However because my nav is fixed, I don't know how to make the main content flex with the popout on hover.

Is there a way to do this without the use of javascript?

Comment: Yes, there's a way. What have you come up with thus far? Show us some code...

Comment: Kind of chaotic, but this is what I have: http://cdpn.io/fwhCL

Comment: If I make the nav relative, it flexes, but its not longer occupying the side.

Comment: You're going to want to do the jQuery route here I think. When you hover over the menu bar - causing it to change width...you need the "main content" to be pushed to the right the same width as the opened menu bar. You dig?

Comment: Cool thanks. I JQUERY'd it up and it works fine: http://cdpn.io/fwhCL.

Comment: Nice! Little tip, speed up things up a bit and remove the "speed" from the js. http://codepen.io/mikebarwick/full/lKazI

Comment: If anyone knows if there is still a way to do this JQUERY free, I would love to know!

Comment: Thanks @MikeBarwick ! I digging the slow creep, but it is a little slow, I will play with the easing and timing more

Comment: I found it annoying personally. People browse the web fast. You're baby though, was just making a suggestion. :D

Comment: @MikeBarwick you are right. After over 200 times of hovering (maybe more), I notice I am growing impatient!